# Generate multiple google maps from an ajax call which returns html from a php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a website that displays a list of properties (retrieved via MySQL from a database).

Every property also has a longitude and latitude value, which is also retrieved from the database which I use to display a google map (per property).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function initialize() 
    {
        var search_results_map = document.getElementById('search_results_map<?php echo $map_count; ?>');

        var property_location = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $lat; ?>', '<?php echo $lng; ?>');

        var mapOptions = {
            center: property_location,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeID: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(search_results_map, mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: property_location,
            map: map
        });
    }

    window.onload = initialize();
</script>
```

The above code creates the map with the $lng and $lat retrieved from the database and puts the map in a previously created div 'search_results_map' + map_count where map_count is merely a count of the number of properties in the list.

This script is inside a while loop that goes through the list of properties retrieved from the database and works fine.

However, I wanted to use ajax to make the pagination, order list by and display x number of records at a time work when the user either changes the select lists or clicks next on the navigation.

So I took the bit of script that gets the list of properties, including the bit that displays the google maps and stuck it into another php file.

When the page first loads, it displays the results via an includes('get_search_results.php') and when the user changes a select box or clicks the navigation, an ajax function calls 'get_search_results.php' and gets the html displaying the results back, which it displays.

This all works fine, however it is at this point, when the ajax call is made that the maps do not work.

So to summarise so far - maps work when the page is first loaded, but do not work when the search results change.

I've narrowed it down to the fact that initialize() is not being called the second time round, which I can understand I think because window.onload isn't working because the window has not been reloaded.

However I've also tried changing it to just initialize() and that doesn't work the second time either.

I've also tried adding a unique number to the end of initialize, so all the functions have individual names. That doesn't make a difference either.

I've also tried just creating the functions in the php script and then after the ajax call is finished, running all the initialize() functions for all the maps (with the unique names) and that throws a javascript error undefined, so I think the problem might be that the functions cannot be found that point, but I can see them in the html code when I inspect element.

Can anyone make any sense of this? I'm not even sure what to google or if I'm barking up the wrong tree completely.

In summary: I want to generate multiple google maps from an ajax call which returns html from a php script.

Comment: The issue is still unclear to me, despite the long explanation... why don't you just request one JSON from your ajax call, containing all the info (lat, lng, etc) for all the maps you want to create? Then you can just loop through your json and create maps on the fly in JS. Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you be a bit more specific about how I would send back both the html containing the search results (and indeed the map container) plus a list of long and lats for all the maps?